# Typescript mutate object add property

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code:

```
type Data = {
    projectID: number;
    foo: string;
}

const projectID = 1;
const datas: Data[] = []
const addToProject = (a: Omit<Data, "projectID">) => {
    a.projectID = projectID; // Property 'projectID' does not exist on type 'Omit<Data, "projectID">'
    datas.push(a);
};

addToProject({
    foo: 'bar',
});
```

The idea is that the object passed to `addToProject` doesnt need a `projectID` property, since in the given context, the projectID is already known and can be added by the function itself.
Inside the function, `a` is converted from `Omit<Data, "projectID">` to `Data`.

###### How can I tell Typescript that I am changing the type of `a`?

I could change the function body to:

```
datas.push({
    ...a,
    projectID
});
```

but for performance reasons I don't want to create a new object.

I could also change every `a` to `a as Data`

```
(a as Data).projectID = projectID;
datas.push(a as Data);
```

but my real function has a lot more occurrences of `a` and this doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

There you are

```
const addToProject = (a: Omit<Data, "projectID">) => {
  const r = a as Data;
  r.projectID = projectID; // Property 'projectID' does not exist on type 'Omit<Data, "projectID">'
  datas.push(r);
};
```

But, honestly, I'd just create a new object. The performance impact is minuscule and it outweighs the risk of mutating an argument.